# MATLAB: while running .m file, only the name of file appears in command window

Tags: matlab

Everything was working fine, when suddenly instead of normal running all of my .m files started producing only the name of file in command window. What happened and how to fix this? Restarting of MATLAB gave no results.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at the Command **History** window, instead of the Command window where output appears?  MatLab remembers the location of each window, so restarting has no effect.  You'll have to go into the menu and re-activate the Command window.

Comment: No. I was looking at Command Window. Just found the problem. I was trying to run files whose names were numbers. Looks like matlab didn't like such names.

Comment: When Matlab sees numbers, it does math.  You can't make a function or script whose name is numeric.